# Matlab: "Error using assignin: Attempt to add "c" to a static workspace"

Tags: matlab, nested, environment-variables, symbolic-math

I have the following piece of function definition (test code):

```
function [X,Y,Z] = test(x,y,z)

syms a b c;
a = b + c;   % This is where it gets wrong

X=x;
Y=y;
Z=z;

keyboard

% nested functions
    function y = fun1(t,x)
        y=t+x;
    end

    function res = bvpbc(y0,yT)
       res= y0+yT;
    end

end
```

Basically, I have some nested functions within the `test` function, where I declared some symbolic variables `a`, `b` and `c`. However, when I run the function by typing

`test(1,1,1)`

there is always this error message:

```
Error using assignin
Attempt to add "b" to a static workspace.
 See MATLAB Programming, Restrictions on Assigning to
 Variables for details.

Error in syms (line 66)
        assignin('caller',x,sym(x));

Error in test (line 3)
    syms a b c;
```

It seems to be something wrong with the symbolic declarations, but I don't understand why. How can I fix it?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** In addition, whenever I remove the two nested functions, the `test` function will work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal working example recreates the problem, and as [Andrew Janke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105904/andrew-janke) explains in the comments, is not a bug:

```
function foo
syms A

    function nested
    end

end
```

you can work around it with an explicit assignment of the symbolic variable to the workspace:

```
A = sym('A');
```

Comment: It's not strictly a bug, just a quirky result of how the Symbolic stuff is implemented as a toolbox, and not in the Matlab syntax itself. While `syms A` may look like a static variable declaration, it isn't. It's just a regular function call. It's using Matlab's "command" invocation style to look like syntax, but it's really equivalent to `syms('a', 'b', 'c')`. And nested functions make the workspace static, so you can't dynamically add vars, which the `syms` function does in its implementation using `assignin`.

Comment: You can probably also work around it by preallocating all the variables with `[a,b,c] = deal([]);` before calling `syms a b c`, too. Might be more concise.