# MATLAB symbolic variables couldn't be used in nested function

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB function to solve a Inertia Tensor , and I have a nested function in my program . All the variables in it are symbolics but it told me

“Error using assignin: Attempt to add ”x“ to a static workspace”

and I don't understand why this happens . Here is my test.m code:

---

```
function test

syms x y z 
f=x
f1=f+1
f2=f1^2
    function r=test2        
        r=f2^3;
    end
f3=test2
end
```

---

After searching this web-forum I have found some answers . But at the same time I just don't understand it

Andrew Janke explianed it like this : **While syms A may look like a static variable declaration, it isn't. It's just a regular function call. It's using Matlab's "command" invocation style to look like syntax, but it's really equivalent to syms('a', 'b', 'c').**
on this page : [Matlab: "Error using assignin: Attempt to add "c" to a static workspace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105493/matlab-error-using-assignin-attempt-to-add-c-to-a-static-workspace)

what does static variable mean ?

I also search the HELP doc and it said :**In functions and scripts, do not use syms to create symbolic variables with the same names as MATLAB® functions. For these names MATLAB does not create symbolic variables, but keeps the names assigned to the functions.**

I only know `syms x` to create a symbolic variable in the workspace but why does the documentation say MATLAB does not create ?

Comment: If we attempt to dynamically add a variable to the workspace of an anonymous function, a nested function, or a function that contains a nested function, then MATLAB® issues an error of the form
what does dynamically add a varibale mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Static' means fixed, 'workspace' is what Matlab calls the places where all of its variables are stored.  For non-nested functions the workspace starts off as empty when Matlab is at the beginning of the function; as Matlab continues through function's lines of code it continuously add more variables to the workspace.

For functions with a nested function, Matlab first parses the function to see what variable will be created (it specifically looks for `x =` type lines), then it creates all of these variables (with value as 'unassigned'), and then only does it start to run through the code; but while running through the code, it can never create a new variable.

This is why the code

```
function TestNestedFunction
syms x;
  function Nested()

  end
end
```

generates an error, there is no `x =` to tell it to pre-create the unassigned variable `x` at the start of the code.  It fails at `syms x;`, as that line tries to create a new variable `x`, which fails as it may not.

This is also why the following code runs

```
function TestNestedFunction
syms x;
x = x;
  function Nested()

  end
end
```

it sees the `x =` and then pre-creates `x`.  (This is why your example of adding `[x, y, z] = deal([]);` also works).

You can test this with a break point at the beginning of simple non-nested function and a simple nested function.  Just run it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I think the pages you found are quite clear.
You need to declare the variables one by one and use:

```
x = sym('x')
```

Otherwise `syms` will try to assign the values into a workspace where this is not allowed.

Comment: sym only takes one input argument

Comment: Thank you all the same for answering ! Actually I want to know the reason why sym would be work but syms not . And more about the meaning of “ preallocating the variables ”, it seems prove that sym work in this way @DennisJaheruddin

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
function test

x=sym('x')
y=sym('y')
z=sym('z')
f=x
f1=f+1
f2=f1^2
    function r=test2        
        r=f2^3;
    end
f3=test2
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! Yeah , it works , but I want to know the difference between syms and sym , they all creat symbolic variable(s) . In this case sym  would be work but syms wouldn't . Could you please explain more about it ? @Daniel R

Comment: The problem has nothing to to with symbolic variables in special, it's common for all variables. `sym` and `syms` use `assignin('caller'...` to assign the variable to the caller workspace if no return variable is used. Using `x=sym('x')` makes the variable `x` available in nested functions as well.

Comment: Appreciate for your patience. Actually I noticed another way to solve it like this , just put    [x y z]=deal([])    before    syms x y z     in a function that contains a nested function , it will work very well and the program could look like more concise . Just don't konw why